# How to run terminator from homebrew list of packages?

Tags: homebrew, osx-elcapitan, terminator

I run the command:

```
brew install terminator
```

under MAC El Capitan and after the suggestion of homebrew to run instead
the command:

```
I don't remember exactly but it had the word gui terminator inside.
```

Package download started and after many installations terminator was downloaded.

When I go to users folder and run the command:

```
brew list
```

'terminator' is in the list.

When I run again

```
brew install terminator
```

I get the following which shows me the version I have:

```
homebrew/gui/terminator-0.98 already installed
```

How can I run it after the command brew list which shows all the downloads I have?